# Fiware cygnus docker installation

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I have questions regarding docker installation of fiware-cygnus:

What docker image should I use, I found at least 3 of them(not sure if this affect installation)
I have agent.conf on my host, and I was not able to map it to the container. So it could be me but is this location where I should map agent.conf?
I had no problems to map my own grouping_rules.conf but agent.conf I was not able to do it, I run docker images/containers many times never had an issue like this.

```
/opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf
```

This is the main reason of my problems because file inside of docker-container simply won't change, even if I try to change it the manual moment I restart container it returns to the original state.
3. Do I need to configure cygnu_instance.conf, very confusing for me is the fact that in it mention agent.conf but on the different location, is that location I should map my agent.conf or not.

```
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent.conf
```

These are the main questions/issues I have:
If someone were able to install Cygnus with docker and with personal agent.conf or know where I should look and send me in some direction would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully sure, but of the 3 I think the one you need to work with Orion Context Broker (i.e. subscribing to Orion so it sends notifications to Cygnus) is `cygnus-ngsi`.

With regards to configuration, I think that the approach is not editing .conf files inside the docker container on execution. You should inject configuration as environment variables. The ENV marks in [the Dockerfile](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/docker/cygnus-ngsi/Dockerfile) mean configurabe parameters.

I guess that both `docker run` and docker-compose should allow to set environment variables to the container, but that's a docker generic question not directly related with this question. There should be a lot of literature out there about this :)

Comment: Build using Dockerfile solved issue(not perfect because of things that could change etc.) but it works with my own config. I will also test using env. Thanks a lot for response.